# Take Screenshot in Flutter web

Tags: flutter-web

How to take a screenshot of a widget in Flutter web?

There is RenderRepaintBoundary Widget which can be used for Mobile and iOS but It is giving error for Web.

Comment: what is wrong with using RenderRepaintBoundary in web ? it works for me

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, import:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
```

Then, it's as easy as:

```
   screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List? value) {
      final _base64 = base64Encode(value!);
      final anchor =
          AnchorElement(href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,$_base64')
            ..download = "image.png"
            ..target = 'blank';
    
      document.body!.append(anchor);
      anchor.click();
      anchor.remove();
    });
```

There you go - saving / downloading an image using flutter web!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as usual if you set the `--web-renderer canvaskit` flag when building/running your web app.

Comment: I can't render canvaskit due to show NetworkImage becauese network needs renered html